# Overflow-y not working with wrapper mobile

Tags: css

On the mobile version of the website, you can scroll to the right to the navigation, which should actually only be accessible via click. How can this be changed?

(URL removed)

I have already tried many different solutions that I have found, but nothing works so far.

I am looking for help in this individual case.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: We need to see your code to help. The relevants parts in html and css and even JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By moving your `.main-nav` element with transform to the right you extend width of the visible content, and since your scroll properties are default it will enable you to scroll the entire visible content, including that menu.

What you want to do is clip everything that is outside of your `html` or `body` element.

CSS

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```